# Is there an optimal season in which to visit the Bamboo Forest in Sagano?

Tags: japan, nature-and-wildlife, national-parks

I might go have a look at the Bamboo Forest in Sagano, Japan in the future.

However, I wanted to make sure I come during the right period.

Does the Bamboo Forest look nice year-round, or are there certain months that it looks different from, for example, [this picture.](https://feel-planet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Bamboo-Forest.-Japan.jpg) I want to make sure I don't miss the Forest as shown in the picture, if I'd go there.

**What are the months that the Bamboo Forest would look different (for example, different colour of the bamboo, no leaves or others)?**

Comment: I went last year by the end of July; It was very hot and humid but bearable (I am from South America).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have read the same CNN travel article by Karla Cripps that I did, [Sagano Bamboo Forest -- a most enchanting  grove](http://www.cnn.com/travel/article/sagano-bamboo-forest/index.html).

Since inclusion on 100 Soundscapes of Japan, it appears that there is no best season, rather better time of day and week to visit: early morning, late evening. The less-crowded seasons are Winter and Summer. Japanese day-trippers descend in Fall and Spring.

Bamboo is an evergreen, so you may want to plan according to what weather and temperatures you prefer. Kyoto and the surrounding area is rather temperate, with hot, humid summers (29°C/83°F average hottest in August), and cold but not freezing winters (5°C/40°F average coldest in January).

[TripAdvisor anecdotal feedback](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g298564-d1386107-r247793945-Sagano-Kyoto_Kyoto_Prefecture_Kinki.html) from both visitors and locals suggest that late Fall (end of November, early December) and late winter (end of February to mid-March) are ideal, with few, if any crowds, and, on occasion, atmospheric conditions (fog, mist) during which the footpaths are illuminated.